# What happens if I do not use body parser or express.json()?

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I am new to the whole backend stuff I understood that both bodyparser and express.json() will parse the incoming request(body from the client) into the request object.

But what happens if I do not parse the incoming request from the client ?

Answer (score 0):

without middleware parsing your requests, your req.body will not be populated. You will then need to manually go research on the req variable and find out how to get the values you want.

Your bodyParser acts as an interpreter, transforming http request, in to an easily accessible format base on your needs.

You may read more on HTTP request here ( You can even write your own http server )
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage

Answer (score 0):

You will just lose the data, and `request.body` field will be empty.

Though the data is still sent to you, so it is transferred to the server, but you have not processed it so you won't have access to the data.

You can parse it yourself, by the way. The request is a `Readable` stream, so you can listen `data` and `end` events to collect and then parse the data.

Answer (score 0):

You shall receive what you asked for in scenarios where you do not convert the data you get the raw data that looks somewhat like this `username=scott&password=secret&website=stackabuse.com`, Now this ain't that bad but you will manually have to filter out which is params, what is a query and inside of those 2 where is the data..

unless it is a project requirement all that heavy lifting is taken care of by express and you get a nicely formatted object looking like this

```
{
 username: 'scott',
 password: 'secret',
 website: 'stackabuse.com' 
}
```

For Situation where you **DO** need to use the raw data express gives you a convenient way of accessing that as well all you need to do is use this line of code
`express.raw( [options] )` along with `express.json( [options] )`